# bash repeat python scripts until succeed

Tags: bash

I am trying to figure out how to use bash to run four python scripts in parallel and when one of them failed, keep running that one until it succeeds.
The code I have right now is

```
while ./test0.py; do :; done &
while ./test1.py ; do :; done &
while ./test2.py ; do :; done &
while ./test3.py ; do :; done
```

However, this seems like keep running until one of them fails.

Is there anyway to achieve keep running the one that's failed until it succeeds?
(I have made them executable, so I did directly ./ )

Comment: I see you have a solution, but personally I would have said the solution should have been inside the python script itself so you could simply call ./test0.py & and whatever is erroring inside the script is being caught as an exception and then retried

Answer (score 2):

Use `until` to invert the test.

```
until ./test0.py; do :; done &
until ./test1.py; do :; done &
until ./test2.py; do :; done &
until ./test3.py; do :; done
```

Comment: It appears that it doesn't re-run. Is it possible that it's the problem with my python script? What should I put in the python script in order for the exit status to be 'failed'? Right now I am just printing the 'error' when not everything goes through (I did try, except in python)

Comment: You need to call `sys.exit()` with a non-zero code.

Comment: Got it! I did sys.exit(1) and it works smoothly. Thanks so much! @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation to the previous answer, we can make the bash script sleep for a while, if we need to wait before testing the completion of the Python code.

```
while ./test.py ; do:; sleep 5m; done
```

The above command checks, if test.py has completed its execution. If not, it keeps checking every 5 mins until we get a sys.exit(0) from the Python code